# update query syntax error in java

Tags: java, database

im trying to make an update query on my java, i keep getting error in my sql syntax but i already tried executing the query in my sqlyog and it worked, but it doesnt work in my program, here is my query

```
String query = "UPDATE t_surat_masuk SET kode_klasifikasi = '"+kode_klasifikasi+"',"

                        + " pengirim = '"+pengirim+"',"
                        + " no_surat = '"+no_surat+"', "
                        + " tgl_surat = '"+tanggalsurat+"',"
                        + " perihal = '"+perihal+"',"
                        + " tgl_surat_masuk = '"+tanggalmasuk+"', "
                        + " penerima = '"+penerima+"', "
                        + " WHERE id_surat='"+id_surat+"'";
```

sorry for my bad english, thank you

Comment: Please also add your schema definition to your answer.

Comment: How are you executing the SQL string? And...what is the Error you are getting?

Comment: i used the '?' but it gave me the same error

Comment: It's `?` with NO quotes around it.  The whole point of statements is that they handle the quoting for you.

Comment: right syntax to use near '?, pengirim = ?, no_surat = ?, tgl_surat = ?, perihal = ?, tgl_surat_masuk = ?, ' at line 1   this is the error if i used the question mark

Comment: I can't see your whole code, so I can't help.  My answer should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exact syntax error is that you have a stray comma after the `SET` clause, before the `WHERE` clause.  But the best answer here is for you to use a prepared statement:

```
String sql = "UPDATE t_surat_masuk SET kode_klasifikasi = ?, pengirim = ?, ";
sql += "no_surat = ?, tgl_surat = ?, perihal = ?, tgl_surat_masuk = ?, penerima = ? ";
sql += "WHERE id_surat = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, kode_klasifikasi);
ps.setString(2, pengirim);
ps.setString(3, no_surat);
ps.setString(4, tanggalsurat);
ps.setString(5, perihal);
ps.setString(6, tanggalmasuk);
ps.setString(7, penerima);
ps.setInt(8, id_surat);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Note that I assumed all columns are strings, except for the `id_surat` column, which sounds like an integer column.  You may have to change the types of some of the above setters to get it to work.

In general, you can see that with a prepared statement, you may write out what is essentially the actual raw query.  This makes it much harder to have syntax errors of the sort you currently have.

Comment: why im getting a parameter index out of range error?

Comment: @LuthfiMusafa You shouldn't be getting that error from my code.